# What is the right way to encode a protobuf serializeBinary response to send it over http post body?

Tags: node.js, spring, encoding, utf-8, http-post

I'm trying to send a protobuf over http post to java spring server from node js client.

`message.serializeBinary()` gives me a uint8 bytes array which I tried to encode with `new StringDecoder('utf8').write(<bytes>)`. And I send it over post with npm request-promise:

```
 const request = require('request-promise')
 const options = {
  uri: <some url>,
  method: 'POST',
  qs: {
    'attr1': 'value1',
    'attr2': new StringDecoder('utf8').write(message.serializeBinary())
  }
}
request(options).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

This hits spring server endpoint

```
@ResponseBody String endpoint(@RequestParam String attr1, @RequestParam String attr2) {
  // This is raising InvalidProtocolBufferException
  var message = Message.parseFrom(attr2.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  
}
```

Looks like encoding issue to me, I'm not sure what encoding to use to transport a protocol buffer over http. Or If i'm doing something else wrong, please point it out too.

Comment: Hi sir, I also encountered this error the same as yours. How did you solve it?

Comment: Problem was sending it in query string, which is truncated based on url length restrictions, I started passing it as form data and that fixed it.

Comment: If you made sure to keep your records on the smaller side, Base64 encoding the protobuf should work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr Solution is to change qs to form

```
const options = {
  uri: <some url>,
  method: 'POST',
  form: {
    'attr1': 'value1',
    'attr2': new StringDecoder('utf8').write(message.serializeBinary())
  }
}
```

Problem was passing encoded protobuf as query string parameter, which is part of url. Url has variable length restriction based on browser, better to pass it as form data. See [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)